# Adjust widths of multiple plots made by lapply, arrangeGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have code to make plots following:
My question is how to adjust the widths of 1st plot and last plot in the figure made?

```
dat=data.frame(x=rep(c("M","D"),each=60),y=rep(rep(c(4,6,8,10,12),each=12),2),z=runif(120,0,100),s=rep(c(1:4),each=3,len=120))

gp=lapply(split(dat,dat$y),function(dfr){
  g=ggplot(data = dfr, aes(s,z)) + 
    geom_point(aes(shape=x,colour=x),size=4)+
    ylim(0,100)+
    xlab("Int segs")+
    ggtitle(paste(dfr[1,2],"hours"))
  return(g)})
tiff(file="Pas.tiff",width=60, height = 22,units="cm",res=300)
require(gridExtra)
rg=arrangeGrob(grobs=list(gp$`4` + theme(legend.position="none"),
                          gp$`6` + theme(legend.position="none",
                                         axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                                         axis.text.y = element_blank()),
                          gp$`8` + theme(legend.position="none",
                                         axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                                         axis.text.y = element_blank()),
                          gp$`10` + theme(legend.position="none",
                                          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                                          axis.text.y = element_blank()),
                          gp$`12` + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                                          axis.text.y = element_blank())),ncol=5,
               top=textGrob("Pas rate",
                            gp=gpar(fontsize=20,fontface="bold"),
                            y = unit(.4, "cm")),
               theme(margin(t=70,r=0.2,b=0.5,l=0.3,unit="mm")))

grid.newpage()
#grid.draw(cbind(lg, rg, size = "last"))
grid.draw(rg)
dev.off()
```

Comment: It's not a strict rule, but in general the site tries to keep the question as short and relevant. Something like "Thank you" is appropriate as a comment on an answer, if at all. My understanding is that the creators of the site feel that this keeps the site distinct from a typical forum, where questions and answers can be difficult to find with all the small talk and commentary mixed in. See, e.g., [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/903061).

Comment: why don't you use facetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd use cbind() here (if facetting isn't an option)

```
gp[[1]] <- gp[[1]] + theme(legend.position="none")
gp[[5]] <- gp[[5]] + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                             axis.text.y = element_blank())
gp[c("6", "8", "10")] <- lapply(gp[c("6", "8", "10")], "+", e2 = theme(legend.position="none",
                                                                       axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                                                                       axis.text.y = element_blank()))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(do.call(gridExtra::cbind.gtable, lapply(gp, ggplotGrob)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is much more better :D

Comment: @baptiste: But how can I add a title of "Pas rate" to the top of the figure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: easiest way might be `grid.arrange(do.call(gridExtra::cbind.gtable, lapply(gp, ggplotGrob)), top="Pas rate")`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `gtable`: you can extract legend and y.label from a first "dummy" plot, then plot each graph within a cell and with the same dimensions (having removed both legend and y.label from all of them, including 1st and last) to then add y.label and legend into separate cells.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gtable)
require(grid)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

dat <- data.frame(x=rep(c("M","D"),each=60),
                  y=rep(rep(c(4,6,8,10,12),each=12),2),
                  z=runif(120,0,100),
                  s=rep(c(1:4),each=3,len=120))

gp <- lapply(split(dat,dat$y),function(dfr){
    g=ggplot(data = dfr, aes(s,z)) + 
        geom_point(aes(shape=x,colour=x),size=4)+
        ylim(0,100)+
        xlab("Int segs")+
        ggtitle(paste(dfr[1,2],"hours"))
    return(g)
})


tiff(file="Pas.tiff",width=60, height = 22,units="cm",res=300)

## Step 1:
## "dummy" plot, just to take y axis title/text and legend
dummy <- ggplotGrob(gp[[1]] + theme(panel.background = element_blank()))$grobs
legend <- dummy[[which(sapply(dummy, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
ytitle <- dummy[[grep("axis.title.y",sapply(dummy, function(x) x$name))]]
yticks <- dummy[[2]]

## Step 2:
## actual plots, all of them without y axis title/text and legend
pp <- 1
tab <- ggplotGrob(gp[[pp]] + theme(legend.position="none",
                                   axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                                   axis.text.y = element_blank()))
for(pp in 2:length(gp)){
    tab <- gtable_add_cols(tab, unit(1,"null"))
    tab <- gtable_add_grob(tab, ggplotGrob(gp[[pp]] + theme(legend.position="none",
                                                            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                                                            axis.text.y = element_blank())), 
                           t = 1, l = ncol(tab), b=nrow(tab), r=ncol(tab))
}

## Step 2:
## adding back ytitle, yticks and legend
## add narrow column to the left and put yticks labels withint
tab <- gtable_add_cols(tab, unit(1,"cm"), pos=0)
tab <- gtable_add_grob(tab, yticks, 
                       t = 3, l = 2, b=nrow(tab)-3, r=1)

## add narrow column to the left and put y.axis label withint
ab <- gtable_add_cols(tab, unit(1,"cm"), pos=0)
tab <- gtable_add_grob(tab, ytitle, 
                       t = 1, l = 1, b=nrow(tab), r=1)

## add narrow column to the right and put legend within
tab <- gtable_add_cols(tab, unit(1.5,"cm"))
tab <- gtable_add_grob(tab, legend, 
                       t = 1, l = ncol(tab), b=nrow(tab), r=ncol(tab))
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tab)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Everything is perfect for me except for the axis.text.y was removed. Could you please help me to check and suggest how to add the text of (0,25,50,75,100) on the y axis beside the y title. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: I had forgotten about the yticks! Now they are back :D
The trick is still the same: add one more cell to the left and put the ticks within; the difference is that you have to select the central cell in the vertical direction (using `t=3,  b=nrow(tab)-3`), to align the ticks to the plot.